# Window resize shifts buttons to the bottom of the page. How to fix the css in this page?

Tags: css, window-resize

I am clueless when it comes to design.
I am trying to put together a landing page kinda thing using a template.
However, when I resize the window the buttons keep shifting to the bottom.

The template is at : http://anandpinky.com/test.html

I've tried a lot of things but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a fix width for the #landing-main...and then the div do not resize anymore

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look at it. It works beautifully.